# When augmenting data, shall the dataset keep a balanced ratio?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, dataset, data-augmentation

When training a model it is more and more common to augment data.
[posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175504/how-to-do-data-augmentation-and-train-validate-split/175844#175844?newreg=c9694029627647ce80449e187c8c1fce) indicate that only the training set shall be augmented.
On the other hand, it is common to split datasets in a fashion following ratios like 70% (train), 15%(validation), 15% (test)

My question is:

- When using augmentation techniques, shall this ratio still be respected after augmentation (meaning that the number of items included in validation and test determines the augmentation ratio)
- or should the dataset be split before the augmentation process (meaning that dataset ratios are unbalanced)?

Any publications regarding this topic?

Answer (score 1):

Using your ratios, it would go something like this.

1. Start with a million images.
2. Select $700,000$ images for training, another $150,000$ for validation, and the final $150,000$ for test.
3. Augment the $700,000$ training images to give yourself $700,001$ or $700,000,000$ images in the training set.
4. Train on the $700,001$ or $700,000,000$ training images.
5. Validated and test your model on the validation set of $150,000$ and test set of $150,000$, respectively.

> You have your data. Create a training set. Now pretend nothing but the training set exists. Augment the training set; train your model on the augmented data. Validate and test on the holdout data sets.

Comment: Not sure that I understood the answer (sorry..) Is that the way I should build my augmentation? Or are you pointing an aberration in my question (which i don't see)?

Comment: You have your data. Create a training set. Now pretend nothing but the training set exists. Augment the training set; train your model on the augmented data. Validate and test on the holdout data sets.

Comment: My intuition - The motivation to augment is to improve the fitting process(reduce variance, etc..). No logic in augmenting the test/validation data.